# Property substitution in domain.xml

Tags: wildfly

My `domain.xml` contains a number of property placeholders like `${com.acme.jdbc.url}` for environment specific settings.

I use a properties file to have these placeholders substituted when starting the domain controller:

```
domain.sh -P domain.properties
```

When starting a slave host with

```
domain.sh --host-config=host-slave.xml
```

the slave fails to start since the placeholders are not substituted.

I have to manually copy the `domain.properties` to the slave host and add them to the command line

```
domain.sh --host-config=host-slave.xml -P domain.properties
```

Is there a way to have to placeholders substituted centrally on the domain controller before the configuration is applied to slaves?

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are resolved at the target host. The model sent by the domain master will preserve the expressions and the slave will resolve them.

You can add a property, e.g. with a CLI command:

```
[domain@localhost:9990 /] /host=master/system-property=com.acme.jdbc.url:add(boot-time=true, value=/mypath)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => undefined,
    "server-groups" => {"main-server-group" => {"host" => {"master" => {
        "server-one" => {"response" => {"outcome" => "success"}},
        "server-two" => {"response" => {"outcome" => "success"}}
    }}}}
}
```

Comment: Will that propagate to all servers in all server groups?